LWC lightning__UrlAddressable Subtab State Error
I have created a subtab component which has a lightning__UrlAddressable target. And I am calling it from another component whose code is given below. The issue which I am getting is that it works fine if the user has "View Setup and Configuration" permission or if the user is having system admin profile.
openSubtabWithLWC(claimNumber, data) {
if (this.isConsoleNavigation) {
  this.displayToast(claimNumber);
  this.isSpinner = true;
  openSubtab(this.parentTabId, {
    pageReference: {
      type: "standard__component",
      attributes: {
        componentName: "c__showClaimDetailsSubTab"
      },
      state: {
        c__recordData: data,
        c__stateKey: claimNumber ? claimNumber : "1",
        uid: claimNumber ? claimNumber : "1"
      }
    },
    label: claimNumber ? claimNumber : "1",
    focus: true
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error in opening tab " + error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.isSpinner = false;
    });
}

}
The c__showClaimDetailsSubTab component utilizes the lightning__UrlAddressable target, which is a feature introduced in the Summer '24 release.
Problem Statement:
I am unable to understand why the "View Setup and Configuration" permission is required for this functionality to work, as this requirement is not documented. Could anyone provide insights into why this permission is necessary and if there are any workarounds?
error which I am getting is:  Error: jobLibrary - Job: preProcessPage, Stage: tasks, Job failed. An error occurred while processing. resolvePage() - Error determining State from pageReference. Source: API, Error: An internal server error has occurred
If more code is needed then let me know, I have not pasted here as the html is lengthy and will take much space. But the subtab is just a display only component which displays data which is being passed from c__recordData property.
Update: This is a bug from Salesforce, so this question remains unanswered until this bug is resolved.
